# This is what my (ps -xa | grep mongod) command returned, and I don't know what it means:

Tags: macos, terminal, grep, ps

```
My-MacBook-Pro:~ peter********$ ps -xa | grep mongod

52360 ??            0:01.43 mongod

52484 ttys000    0:00.00 grep mongPPPPPetPetPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPeters-MacBook-PrPeterPPPetPePetersPetPeterPeters-MaPetPetePePePeters-MacPeters-MacBookPeters-Peters-MacPeters-Pe
```

any, that last part keeps going on, and it really confuses me. What the heck? Also, what do the 52360 and 52484 refer to, and why does one have two question marks? All I'm trying to do is get mongodb up and running, but I can't even find the directory in which it's located. Ah, so confusing.

Thanks for any observations or help!

Answer (score 0):

The numbers are Process IDs for the two processes you found. Your `mongod` process has ID of `52360`. The process you've just launched that you're trying to find `mongod` with is `52484`.

`ttys000` is the terminal device you have launched your `grep` command from. `mongod` was started by the system, not from a terminal, so does not have a terminal device attached to it. Nothing to worry about there.

I am not sure why your `grep` command got corrupted; but it has nothing to do with `mongod` itself, so feel free to disregard it.

The way to find any file on Mac OS X, if the index is up-to-date:

```
mdfind mongod
```

If the file is an executable that you are able to execute, you can reliably find it using

```
which mongod
```

The way to find a file that came from a package depends on the way it was packaged (i.e. if you just copied an app into your `/Applications`, or if you used Homebrew, or `ports`, `fink`, or a `.pkg` file, or something else).

The way to find the current working directory of a process:

```
lsof -a -d cwd -p 52360
```

where 52360 is the process ID as explained above (this is probably not the location of the executable, but you might want to know).